# "From (just) this data (alone), we can conclude..."

Tags: meaning, expressions

In the context of scientific writing, is there a difference in meaning between these options?

- From just this data, we can conclude...
- From this data alone, we can conclude...
- From just this data alone, we can conclude...

Although all options seem to convey the same meaning, I'd avoid the third option unless I wanted to emphasize the "only this set of data" aspect. That seems to leave the first two options to have the same meaning. Are they truly the same, or is there a subtlety I'm missing?

Comment: In scientific writing you would say "From this data...".  You wouldn't use either just or alone.

Comment: Or even "*these data*".  ;o)

Comment: They are used for emphasis, nothing more.  Doesn't change the meaning of the sentence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, they are the same. However, the more words you add to your concluding statement, the more wishy-washy you appear in a scientific setting. Also, a single summation sentence generally becomes part of the abstract where character count should be minimized.

I'd suggest:

**From this data we conclude ...**

All your other words are understood.

Comment: If you want to make a standout point, underline whatever word you wish to emphasize.  Otherwise agreeing with Stu that the other words are understood.

Comment: Suppose that **data** was introduced on previous line. Can we write *... from where we conclude...*?

Comment: *from which we conclude...*